# What is the difference between Celery and Kombu

Tags: python, celery, messaging, kombu

I know that is a hard question, and we have a similar question here 
[differentiate-celery-kombu-pyamqp-and-rabbitmq-ironmq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121519/differentiate-celery-kombu-pyamqp-and-rabbitmq-ironmq)

But I'm still confused about the difference between each other

Celery is a distributed message queue and they cover the producer and consumer

Kombu is a messaging library for Python. and they also cover producer and consumer

My main question is, what is the difference between each other?

Comment: IIRC Celery uses the Kombu library to send and receive messages.